# Join multiple strings with delimiters

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, linq

I would like to join multiple strings in my format:

```
Like: string1:string2,string1:string2, and more...
```

I have list with string1 and string2 values.

```
string test = String.Join(",", mylist.Select(x => x.string1));
```

How can I join these variables in my format ?

Comment: So you want to alternate between string1 and string2?

Comment: What makes the difference between `string1` and `string2`, that they come in pairs?

Comment: There are variables from my list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming:

- `string1` and `string2` are properties from a custom object
- `mylist` is a generic list of this custom object

---

You could just change your `Select` like this:

```
string.Join(",", mylist.Select(x => string.Format("{0}:{1}", x.string1, x.string2));
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you

```
string result = string.Join(",", myList.Select(x=> string.Join(":", x.string1, x.string2)));
```

Comment: I am assuming the same as Sebastian Sevrin is in his answer here.